# Отсутствует шрифт для русскоязычных комментариев кода в Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, шрифты, safari, google-colaboratory

Использую браузер Chrome на Macbook Pro M1, и почему-то русскоязычные комментарии отображаются с каким-то кривым шрифтом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В то время как в Safari всё в порядке:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я правильно понимаю, что в Chrome не загружен шрифт, видимо? Можете подсказать, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема и как её решить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать - в правом верхнем углу браузера Chrome, три вертикальные точки (Настройки и управление Google Chrome), выбираем настройки - внешний вид - настроить шрифты.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось! В качестве моноширинного выбрал "Courier New", шрифт стал более блеклым, но теперь всё отображается нормально

Comment: Хорошо! Ну, а размытость шрифтов это еще одна проблема Chrome. Я как-то разбирался, но простых и полных решений не нашел.